# Alternative to Amazon’s S3 service?

Tags: file, amazon-s3, storage, cloud

Just wondering if there is good alternative to Amazon's S3 service? I like S3 but the bandwidth cost is high. I looked at CouldFiles from Rackspace but the cost is even higher.

I don't mind prepaying or having monthly payment in order to reduce the bandwidth cost greatly.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Are you taking advantages of Expires headers with your S3 files?

Comment: OK - just wanted to check before I wrote a detailed answer about them! Unfortunately I'm not aware of an easy way to get much cheaper bandwidth than S3 without being a large scale buyer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer here is that S3 is pretty competitive, especially when you take into account the feature set that you get with S3.  I've yet to come across something similar to S3 that is both cheaper, and has the core features that make S3 so nice.